# Is there a way to allow a standard user access to Active Directory on a remote server?

Tags: active-directory, uac, windows-server-2012-r2

I'll do my best to explain this, but apologies if it doesn't come across well.

We have a remote SharePoint web-server (Windows 2012 R2) on a server farm that we RDP into to add users, create site collections etc.

We have one or two users on our helpdesk who's task on the server is to create/edit users or reset passwords. I've tried to set them up as a standard user and delegate control within AD to them to be able to do these tasks, but when they log in and open *Active Directory Users and Computers* they are prompted for the Admin user/password.

Is there a way to give them access to AD without elevating them to admin or domain controller, which I don't want to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is really with `mmc.exe`, since ADUC (`dsa.msc`) is really just a snap-in for MMC. One thing you could try is to tell Windows to always run `mmc.exe` with whatever elevation it was started with, and not to trigger UAC. You can do this by setting the compatibility option to `RunAsInvoker`.

There are a couple ways to do this. To set it for the whole computer, you can set it in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\mmc.exe"="RunAsInvoker"
```

You can change that to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` if you only want it to apply to each user.

Another way is to create a shortcut that sets the `__COMPAT_LAYER` environment variable before starting it, so the setting only applies to that one shortcut:

```
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START dsa.msc"
```

Comment: I've used the second option and it's worked a treat. Thanks @Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gabriel Luci helped me a lot!
The CMD line runs like a champ.
hier are a list to run other Active Directory Management Consoles with that:

```
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START ADSIedit.msc"
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START DSA.msc"
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START GPmc.msc"
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START domain.msc"
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START dnsmgmt.msc"
cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START dsite.msc"
```

- ADSIedit.msc = ADSIedit
- DSA.msc      = "Active Directory Users and
  Computers" (ADUC)
- GPmc.msc = "Group Policy Management"
- domain.msc = "Active Directory Domains and Trusts"
- dnsmgmt.msc  = "DNS Management"
- dsite.msc = "Active Directory Sites and Services"