# Is there a way to allow a standard user access to Powershell run as admin on a remote server?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been following this thread originally ([Is there a way to allow a standard user access to Active Directory on a remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408394/is-there-a-way-to-allow-a-standard-user-access-to-active-directory-on-a-remote-s)) and it has given alot of info to work from. We can control access to the MMC.exe through AD permissions, but our users require elevation to Admin of the server to be able to run Powershell for the tasks they do. (working on resolving that through another piece of work).

We need to find a way to still give them elevated access to Powershell, but without actually granting explicit admin access to the whole server.

Is there a regedit, or cmd they can run, similar to this (cmd.exe /c "SET __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker & START dsa.msc") but for Powershell?

Cheers

Comment: There is a way, it's called [PowerShell JEA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-7.2) - you configure a PowerShell remoting endpoint on the remote server, and give your user access to connect, the remoting endpoint will then run the user's code under a different security context on the server

Answer (score 0):

•   There is a way through which you don’t have to grant administrator privileges to your remote users who want to connect remotely to powershell. You will need to make a GPO (Group Policy Object) in your central policy server and set the policy as below to allow the users to access powershell without administrator privileges: -

Default domain policy/New GPO --> Edit --> Computer Configuration --> Policies --> Windows Settings --> Security settings --> Restricted groups --> Remote Management Users --> Click on ‘Add’ --> Select the users from Active Directory --> Ok

[image: RemoteManagementUsersGPO]

Once, you do this, then ensure that this policy is pushed on all the systems where you want users to run powershell remotely with administrator privileges. You can also add those users in a group and then add that group as a member of the ‘Remote management users’ group through group policy.

•   You can check the permissions of a powershell session through the below command which clearly states that ‘Remote Management users’ are allowed access to the powershell session remotely. Please note that Windows Remote Management service needs to be started and run for the below command to run successfully and provide you with results.

```
  ‘ (Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell).Permission ‘
```